# 06 Cobalt - Car dies while driving and won't start back up

Tags: engine

Car dies while driving and won't start back up - turn key no clicking no nothing - all gauges and lights light up - battery charged . Can jump across starter and it starts and dies. One mechanic says bad starter - auto parts store says starter passes

Comment: If you can jump the starter and it works, it's probably no that, right?  Has the battery been tested?  Just looking at voltage or trying to charge it isn't enough.

Comment: Battery was at 12.1v and with a tester showed good

Comment: Right, but I'm saying that _just_ the voltage is meaningless on its own.  A battery can show 12v, but still be internally damaged and not be able to start the car.

Comment: Sounds like battery to me also. Take the battery to a car spares store (or even a Walmart) and ask them to do a full test on it. If this is the original battery, it's definitely time for a new one.

Comment: Any security light flashing? Does the check engine light turn on when the key is in the on position? Is the check engine light on with the car running?